# AWS SDK - Invoke Lambda function no response on success

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've setup a Lambda function and it is working fine. Now I want to invoke the function from my node.js Server, see below:

```
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda({ region: 'my-region', maxRetries: 0, httpOptions: { connectTimeout: 720000, timeout: 720000 } }); //12min
const params = {
  FunctionName: 'my-function-name',
  Payload: JSON.stringify({
    myPayload
  })
};

try {
  const res = await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
  console.log(res);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

This is also invoking the function and it also finishes correctly. The problem is that it does not return a response, it rather times out. Despite the successful finish of the function.

Any idea why that could be the case?

EDIT:
Short note my function takes about 10 mins to execute. I just tested it with a faster function (1min) and it worked as expected. So maybe its a Bug if it takes to long?

Comment: does your lambda function inside the VPC ? if yes do you have port open in security group of lambda function for server from where you invoking the function ?

Comment: Yes and yes :) As I said I can invoke the function successfully so it reaches the Lambda function and executes it. It just never returns a value if succeded or not.

Comment: I think you're now saying that the invoked Lambda function actually takes 10+ minutes to complete by which time the calling node.js client has timed out, yes? And you're wondering if that's a bug. How can we know if it's a bug? Would you expect the Lambda function to take that long to do whatever it is that it does (none of which we can see)?

Comment: @DeepakGupta security groups are irrelevant here (beyond allowing the calling node.js client to connect to the AWS Lambda service endpoint). Lambda function invocation is not controlled by security groups.

Comment: @jarmod No I'm saying the lambda function takes 10 mins, my node.js timeout is 12 min. So its all fine. My edit was just saying that it did work if the request was faster, nevertheless it should also work for longer request

Comment: OK, so the problem is resolved and can be closed?

Comment: What no, I just specified the issues. My setup works for short request but if the lambda function takes a long time I never get any reponse.